# missing values - Hot Deck neighbour method

Tags: r

I'm having a problem with R code, rather, with missing values. Don't know actually, how to impute those values using simple Hot Deck method. Like, example, having these data.

```
1  10000123  111  112820 0.24457235         NA        NA         NA         NA     11
2  10000132  111 2502357 0.19408587 0.19373610 0.6567305 0.01454520 0.13498823     69
3  10000388  111 4472360 0.14774927 0.14918678 0.6853377 0.05233508 0.11314044    106
4  10000792  111  666909 0.10520063         NA        NA         NA         NA     14
5  10002737  111 1139613 0.19944986 0.20114918 0.3564355 0.20135391 0.24106136     23
6  10002741  111  981574 0.11573570         NA        NA         NA         NA     13
7  10002929  111 1417192 0.08770932 0.08387991 0.6106012 0.11078473 0.19473415     24
8  10003396  111  444966 0.19026263 0.18784110 0.5215772 0.16844381 0.12213789     24
9  10003517  111 1230589 0.16393216 0.16358568 0.4614005 0.26670712 0.10830670     19
10 10003546  111  760847 0.12384748         NA        NA         NA         NA     10
```

Using 5th column, need to find the nearest value, and then fill with that similar  respondent in those places, where are NA values.

Thank You.

Comment: Please use `dput` to provide your data. And to format code use code formating icon `{}` (or align with four spaces), see also http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help.

Comment: actually, didnt get it, but, changed, to understand something :)

Comment: I add data formatting. But when you want to post sample data you could use `dput` command, like `dput(my_data)` (or `head(dput(my_data))`), which create string representation of R object with all details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've never used hot (or cold for that matter) deck sampling. However a little Googling led me to the `rrp.impute` function in the rrp package.

Here's a simple example using some synthetic data:

```
install.packages("rrp")
require(rrp)
set.seed(1)
key <- 1:100
## create random values
value1 <- 10 + 2 * key + rnorm(100, 0, 10)
## make 5 values into NAs
missing <- sample( key, 5)
value1[missing] <- NA
## build a dataframe
df <- data.frame(key, value1)
## do a nearest neighbor hot deck interpolation
imputed <- rrp.impute( df )$new.data

## let's visualize this magic
plot( df)
points(missing, imputed$value1[missing], col="red")
```

This uses the default value of k=1, which is what I think you want. The pretty picture at the end looks like this:

[image]

The red circles are the imputed values and you can see they are simply the nearest neighbor.

Comment: About searching over internet: inside-R has great search engine through R package documentation, [search for hotdeck](http://www.inside-r.org/search/node/hotdeck) or [hot deck](http://www.inside-r.org/search/node/hot%20deck) gives few results.

Comment: Google is doing consistently better (at least for me) with R. Here's the search I did: http://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=hot+deck+imputation+r&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a ready-made R package, but this does the trick:

```
dfr<-data.frame(c1=c(123,132,388,792,2737,2741,2929,3396,3517,3546),
 c2=c(0.244,0.194,0.47,0.105,0.199,0.115,0.087,0.190,0.163,0.123),
 c3=c(NA, 0.193,0.149, NA, 0.201, NA, 0.083,0.187,0.163,NA))

hdidx<-which(!is.na(dfr[,3]))
hd<-dfr[hdidx,]
md<-dfr[-hdidx,]
closesthd<-sapply(md[,2], function(curval){which.min(abs(curval-hd[,2]))})
md[,3]<-hd[closesthd,3]
```

Replace column numbers where needed for your case + maybe take another distance measure.